# Why is pygame button not functioning?

Tags: python, button, pygame

I have been following a tutorial from [Sentdex](https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-button-function-events/) to create a button and make it functional. I tried to change it as per my requirement. When I click on the button, I want the function(another screen) to execute. I placed a button in the function(another screen) where I can go back to the main page. But when I click on the button, it goes to the other function only when I clicked the mouse and the output is displayed just until I click the mouse. It does not go to another screen and keeps on staying at initial screen.

```
import pygame
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 800), pygame.RESIZABLE)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic, (x, y, w, h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def home_intro():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                 
        window.blit(image, (0,0))
        pygame.display.set_caption("PROGRAM")
        button("Start", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), start)
        button("Stop", 550, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), stop)
        pygame.display.flip()


home_intro()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I have followed everything as the tutorial. But I don't understand why it does not work. How can I fix this  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a variable that stores the current state of the game (`game_state` ). Change the variable when a button is clicked and draw different scenes depending on the state of the variable:

```
game_state = "stop"

def start():
    global game_state
    game_state = "start" 

def stop():
    global game_state
    game_state = "stop"
```

```py
def home_intro():
    global game_state

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                 
        window.blit(image, (0,0))
        button("Start", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), start)
        button("Stop", 550, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), stop)

        if game_state == "start":
            # [...]

        else:
            # [...]

        pygame.display.flip()
```